# Refer to different state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

When my is initiated I get directed to this state:

```
$stateProvider.state('dashboard.tasks.overview')
```

I have a link that I want to use to go into a new state

```
<div ui-sref="responsive.details({id:'6710cc8c-e0ca-e811-80fd-00155d168404'})">click</div>
```

And a routeconfig with `$stateProvider.state('responsive.details')`

When I click the link I get:

> Possibly unhandled rejection: {"$id":2,"type":4,"message":"This transition is invalid","detail":"Could not resolve 'responsive.details' from state 'dashboard.tasks.overview'"}

So when I click the link it triest to find the `responsive.details` child route in the `dashboard.tasks.overview`. Is it possible to direct a ui-sref to a new route instead of a child route in a parent?

Answer (score 0):

In ui-router, states are built up in a hierarchy. This means that the `responsive.details` state is a child of the `responsive` state. When you navigate to some state, any parent states of that state must also be loaded.

In your example, you never mentioned creating a `responsive` state.

Add some sort of `$stateProvider.state('responsive', {...});` call.

Alternatively, just rename the `responsive.details` state to `responsiveDetails`, as a test.

See the [ui-router documentation for states](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views).